# Disable URL Encoding of Equals sign in a Parameter Value

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

I have this code below that creates the query parameter collection for a restful web service call

```
NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
outgoingQueryString.Add("SessionID", _sessionId);
outgoingQueryString.Add("LoanNumberID", loanId.ToString());
outgoingQueryString.Add("Nonce", _nonce);
outgoingQueryString.Add("OtherParams", "Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0");
```

The problem is that the last parameter value Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0 get's it's '=' encoded to %3d `SessionID=319A561B6D&LoanNumberID=351591&Nonce=3262383361&OtherParams=Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report%3d0`

when it should be

```
SessionID=319A561B6D&LoanNumberID=351591&Nonce=3262383361&OtherParams=Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0
```

short of doing a rewrite after the fact is there a way to prevent this from happening? The service does not return the proper results set because it interprets the %3d as something it needs to filter.

What I did to fix the issue was the following. I just didn't know if there was a way to prevent this in the first place.

```
string queryString = outgoingQueryString.ToString().Replace("%3d", "=");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get `NameValueCollection` to do what you want; you're probably stuck with a workaround of some sort.

I do see a potential problem in your workaround implementation:

```cs
[Fact]
public void ProblemWithOriginalSolution()
{
    NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
    outgoingQueryString.Add("Param1", "Value1");
    outgoingQueryString.Add("Param2", "Value2=Something"); // this '=' needs to remain URL-encoded
    outgoingQueryString.Add("OtherParams", "Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0");

    var queryString = outgoingQueryString.ToString().Replace("%3d", "=");

    Assert.Contains("Value2=Something", queryString); // Passes, but not what we want
    Assert.Contains("Value2%3dSomething", queryString); // Actually what we want, but fails
}
```

That might not matter for your needs, but if it does, I have two suggestions.

The first is to just use string concatentation. Depending on your use, this might need extra logic to handle the case where `OtherParams` is the only query string parameter (the ampersand should be omitted in that case). String concatenation is also a bad idea of `OtherParams` might contain characters that need to be URL encoded.

```cs
[Fact]
public void Concatentation()
{
    NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
    outgoingQueryString.Add("Param1", "Value1");

    var queryString = outgoingQueryString.ToString() + "&OtherParams=Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0";

    Assert.Contains("&OtherParams=Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0", queryString);
}
```

The second is to do a double-substitution. This is a bit heavy-handed, and not terribly efficient, but should be reliable.

```cs
[Fact]
public void DoubleSubstitution()
{
    // Make sure the placeholder doesn't have any characters that will get URL encoded!
    // Also make sure it's not something that could appear in your input.
    const string equalsPlaceholder = "__Equals__";

    NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
    outgoingQueryString.Add("Param1", "Value1");

    // First, remove the equals signs from the OtherParams value
    outgoingQueryString.Add("OtherParams", "Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0".Replace("=", equalsPlaceholder));

    // Then, build the query string, and substitute the equals signs back in
    var queryString = outgoingQueryString.ToString().Replace(equalsPlaceholder, "=");

    Assert.Contains("&OtherParams=Enable_Filter_Show_on_Action_Report=0", queryString);
}
```

Comment: Those are valid points for consideration. However, in my particular implementation, these parameters are required by the service and will not change in future calls.